# Tailwind-elements table accordion not functioning after refresh or npm run dev/build. Saving the page after a refresh, however, works

Tags: tailwind-css, accordion

Copy-pasting code for a tailwind-elements works perfectly in my vite-react app. Refreshing the page or running npm run dev breaks it.I followed the step by step instructions to get it started. When I copy-paste the code for an accordion ( or any of the other drop down types of elements ) they work perfectly. But when I refresh my page or do an npm run dev and npm run build, the accordion just stops dropping down. But when I ctrl+s to save it, it works again for that session.

import React from 'react' import { Collapse, initTE, } from "tw-elements";

initTE({ Collapse });

Google

```
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="border border-t-0 border-neutral-200 bg-white dark:border-neutral-600 dark:bg-neutral-800">
            <h2 className="mb-0" id="head2">
              <button
                className="group relative flex w-full items-center rounded-none border-0 bg-white px-5 py-4 text-left text-base text-neutral-800 transition [overflow-anchor:none] hover:z-[2] focus:z-[3] focus:outline-none dark:bg-neutral-800 dark:text-white [&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:bg-white [&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:text-primary [&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:[box-shadow:inset_0_-1px_0_rgba(229,231,235)] dark:[&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:bg-neutral-800 dark:[&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:text-primary-400 dark:[&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:[box-shadow:inset_0_-1px_0_rgba(75,85,99)]"
                type="button"
                data-te-collapse-init
                data-te-collapse-collapsed
                data-te-target="#collapseHeadTwo"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="collapseHeadTwo"
              >
                Aniview
                <span className="-mr-1 ml-auto h-5 w-5 shrink-0 rotate-[-180deg] fill-[#336dec] transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:mr-0 group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:rotate-0 group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:fill-[#212529] motion-reduce:transition-none dark:fill-blue-300 dark:group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:fill-white">
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke-width="1.5"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    className="h-6 w-6"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div
              id="collapseHeadTwo"
              className="!visible hidden"
              data-te-collapse-item
              aria-labelledby="head2"
              data-te-parent="#accordionExample2"
            >
              <div>
                <AniviewList
                  start_date={selectedRange && selectedRange[0]}
                  end_date={selectedRange && selectedRange[1]}
                  report_by= {initialValues.report_by}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="rounded-b-lg border border-t-0 border-neutral-200 bg-white dark:border-neutral-600 dark:bg-neutral-800">
            <h2 className="mb-0" id="head3">
              <button
                className="group relative flex w-full items-center border-0 bg-white px-5 py-4 text-left text-base text-neutral-800 transition [overflow-anchor:none] hover:z-[2] focus:z-[3] focus:outline-none dark:bg-neutral-800 dark:text-white [&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:bg-white [&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:text-primary [&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:[box-shadow:inset_0_-1px_0_rgba(229,231,235)] dark:[&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:bg-neutral-800 dark:[&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:text-primary-400 dark:[&:not([data-te-collapse-collapsed])]:[box-shadow:inset_0_-1px_0_rgba(75,85,99)] [&[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:rounded-b-[15px] [&[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:transition-none"
                type="button"
                data-te-collapse-init
                data-te-collapse-collapsed
                data-te-target="#collapseHeadThree"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="collapseHeadThree"
              >
                Outbrain
                <span className="-mr-1 ml-auto h-5 w-5 shrink-0 rotate-[-180deg] fill-[#336dec] transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:mr-0 group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:rotate-0 group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:fill-[#212529] motion-reduce:transition-none dark:fill-blue-300 dark:group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:fill-white">
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke-width="1.5"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    className="h-6 w-6"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div
              id="collapseHeadThree"
              className="!visible hidden"
              data-te-collapse-item
              aria-labelledby="head3"
              data-te-parent="#accordionExample2"
            >
              <div>
                <OutbtainList
                  start_date={selectedRange && selectedRange[0]}
                  end_date={selectedRange && selectedRange[1]}
                />
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
```